# Sharing queries between Rx and LINQ (or generically, streams and lists)

Tags: c#, linq, scala, haskell, system.reactive

How can one go about sharing query logic between LINQ and Rx?  i.e., if I need to sometimes query against an `IObservable` stream and sometimes against an `IEnumerable`, but the exact same logic is in each, is there any way to share that logic?

Maybe an example will help.  In the following `Queries` class, I want to combine the sequence of people and purchases to produce a "notice" string.  Notice I have to duplicate the exact same logic; all that's different is that one is `IEnumerable` and one is `IObservable`.  Is there any way of consolidating these two functions?  I've tried using various combinations of `ToObservable` and `ToEnumerable`, but everything I've tried seems to either hang or produce no result.

(Higher-kinded question: Is this the exact thing that the idea of higher-kinded types was created to solve? i.e., would this not even be a problem in Haskell or Scala?)

```
static class Queries {
    static IObservable<string> GetPurchaseNotices(IObservable<Person> people, IObservable<Purchase> purchases) {
        return from person in people
               from purchase in purchases
               where person.Id == purchase.PurchaserId
               select person.Name + " purchased a " + purchase.ItemName;
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetPurchaseNotices(IEnumerable<Person> people, IEnumerable<Purchase> purchases) {
        return from person in people
               from purchase in purchases
               where person.Id == purchase.PurchaserId
               select person.Name + " purchased a " + purchase.ItemName;
    }
}

class Person {
    public Person(int id, string name) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
}

class Purchase {
    public Purchase(int purchaserId, string itemName) {
        PurchaserId = purchaserId;
        ItemName = itemName;
    }
    public int PurchaserId;
    public string ItemName;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching from observable to enumerable is not a good idea since the enumerable will block, so it will be less problematic the other way around. You should be able to use a single function that filters an `IObservable<Person>`.

Here's simple program that demonstrates the idea. Notice it uses a single method for filtering `IObservable<int>`. In case of `IEnumerable<int>`, it switches `ToObservable` before calling the method, and then switches back `ToEnumerable` after getting the result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var observableNums = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                                   .Select(x => (int)x);
    var observableOdds = FilterOdds(observableNums);
    observableOdds.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

    var enumerableNums = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    var enumerableOdds = FilterOdds(enumerableNums.ToObservable());
    foreach (var i in enumerableOdds.ToEnumerable())
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static IObservable<int> FilterOdds(IObservable<int> nums)
{
    return nums.Where(i => i % 2 == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not possible in C# (or F#) directly. The problem is that while you can abstract over the generic argument `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` or `IObservable<T>`, you cannot abstract over the "kind" `IEnumerable` or `IObservable`.

With higher-kinded types, like those in Haskell or Scala, you could express this given a suitable interface for `IEnumerble` and `IObservable`. In Haskell, it would look something like:

```
getPurchases :: MonadPlus m => m Person -> m Purchaser -> m String
getPurchases people purchases = do
  person <- people
  purchase <- purchases
  if (personId person) == (purchaserId purchase)
    then return $ (name person) ++ "purchased a " ++ (itemName purchase)
    else mzero
```

which you could then use for both `IEnumerable` and `IObservable`.

I don't know whether IObservable actually satisfies the required laws for `MonadPlus` however, so this is just an example.

Comment: Quick follow-up, I notice that `STM` is `MonadPlus`.  Would the `getPurchases` function make any sense to use in the `STM` context?  I have a difficult time understanding a use case.

Comment: Okay, I got that working; it turns out to be a transaction that doesn't succeed until the person and the purchase TVars match on the ID.